# Reverse reading a text file in c

Tags: c, linux, file-io

How can i read for example 10 last lines from a text file beginning from last line? do you have some idea in c?

Comment: I'd look at each char, until you get to the end of the file.  Keep track of how many cr/lf you pass, then read lines in backwards from the bottom until your cr/lf count is 10 less than the total...

Comment: @Cody Gray: i don't know how should i do this. one simple way i know, read all file lines, then show last 10 line that are in an array?

Comment: @AliAzimi: Do you know how to read the last byte of a file?  The last 10 bytes?  Do you know how to figure out if the last 10 bytes **are** the last 10 lines?

Comment: thank you dormann, i done it.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to read the last n bytes from the file in a buffer than operate on that buffer. For example, to read the last BUFFER_SIZE bytes from a file, you could do something like this using stdio:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
FILE* file = fopen("filename", "rb");
size_t bytesRead = -1;

if(file) {
    fseek(file, BUFFER_SIZE, SEEK_END);
    bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, file);

    /* Process the buffer here */
}

fclose(file);
file = NULL;
```